# How do you enable a20 in nasm?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I'm trying to go to long mode in my bootloader and now I'm on the first part with enabling the a20 line but I've encountered a problem and that is that my code that i made just made the screen completely black and the number that should say if it worked didn't even show

I've tried many different a20 functions on the internet but nothing has worked yet for me.

The code for the functions is:

```
check_a20:
    pushf
    push ds
    push es
    push di
    push si
    cli
    xor ax, ax ; ax = 0
    mov es, ax
    not ax ; ax = 0xFFFF
    mov ds, ax
    mov di, 0x0500
    mov si, 0x0510
    mov al, byte [es:di]
    push ax
    mov al, byte [ds:si]
    push ax
    mov byte [es:di], 0x00
    mov byte [ds:si], 0xFF
    cmp byte [es:di], 0xFF
    pop ax
    mov byte [ds:si], al
    pop ax
    mov byte [es:di], al
    mov ax, 0
    je check_a20_exit
    mov ax, 1
    check_a20_exit:
    pop si
    pop di
    pop es
    pop ds
    popf
ret

seta20: ;Enable the a20 line if it worked then ax = 1 else 0
    pusha
    call check_a20 ;Check a20
    cmp ax, 1
    je .end ;If it worked then end function else:
    .keyboard: ;Test the 8042 keyboard controller
        call .empty_8042
        mov al, 0xd1 ;command write
        out 0x64, al
        call .empty_8042
        mov al, 0xdf ; A20 on
        out 0x60, al
        call .empty_8042 ;wait
    .empty_8042: ;For the 8042 function over this
        in al, 0x64
        test al, 2
        jnz .empty_8042
    ret
    call check_a20  ;Check a20
    cmp ax, 1
    je .end ;If it worked then end function else:
    .fasta20:
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al
    .end:
    popa
    call check_a20
ret
```

And after these functions i had a function for printing ax as hex:

```
main:

    ;Stack, video and other setups(not important)

    call seta20 ;Set a20

    mov dl, 00h ;Set cursor for a print a20 check
    mov dh, 01h 
    mov bh, 00h
    mov ah, 02h
    int 10h

    call check_a20 ;Check a20
    mov dl, al
    mov bl, 02h
    call printhex ;Print dl

    jmp $   ;Infinite loop

printhex: ;print hex input(dl=value, bl=color) 8 bit
    pusha
    mov dh, 0x00
    mov ch, dl ;unshifted (for next hex)
    shr dl, 4 ; get high 4 bits(HEX)
    cmp dl, 9
    jna .1to9 
    .atof: ;if the number is a to f
        add dl, 55
        jmp .next
    .1to9:
        add dl, 48 ;add 48 to make it into a number
    .next:
        mov ah, 0Eh ;print char mode
        mov bh, 0
        mov al, dl
        int 10h ;Print 1st number of the two
    shl ch, 4
    mov dl, ch
    shr dl, 4 ; get high 4 bits(HEX)
    cmp dl, 9
    jna .1to92 
    .atof2: ;if the number is a to f
        add dl, 55
        jmp .print2
    .1to92:
        add dl, 48 ;add 48 to make it into a number
    .print2:
        mov ah, 0Eh ;print char mode
        mov bh, 0
        mov al, dl
        int 10h ;Print 1st number of the two
     popa
ret
```

I already knew that my function for printing the results worked because I had tested it so many times but what should happen is that it should print a hex number with my `printhex16`
function that I had

Comment: You have `out 0x60, al`
        `call .empty_8042`
    .`empty_8042:` . I think you are missing a JMP after the call to skip over the `empty_8042` function?

Comment: No, i have a `ret` in the `empty_8042` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methodology behind your A20 code looks okay, but it appears you have a bug in how you have implemented it. You have this code for `seta20`:

```
seta20: ;Enable the a20 line if it worked then ax = 1 else 0
    pusha
    call check_a20 ;Check a20
    cmp ax, 1
    je .end ;If it worked then end function else:
    .keyboard: ;Test the 8042 keyboard controller
        call .empty_8042
        mov al, 0xd1 ;command write
        out 0x64, al
        call .empty_8042
        mov al, 0xdf ; A20 on
        out 0x60, al
        call .empty_8042 ;wait
    .empty_8042: ;For the 8042 function over this
        in al, 0x64
        test al, 2
        jnz .empty_8042
    ret
    call check_a20  ;Check a20
    cmp ax, 1
    je .end ;If it worked then end function else:
    .fasta20:
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al
    .end:
    popa
    call check_a20
ret
```

The problem is that you have placed a function inside another and have inadvertently allowed your code to fall into the function. In particular these lines of code are the issue:

```
        out 0x60, al
        call .empty_8042 ;wait
    .empty_8042: ;For the 8042 function over this
        in al, 0x64
        test al, 2
        jnz .empty_8042
        ret
    call check_a20  ;Check a20
```

`call .empty_8042` will call into the function `.empty_8042`, the 8042 will be flushed; `ret` will return to the instruction after `call .empty_8042` and will then start executing code in `.empty_8042`. The problem is the second time it isn't being called as a function so there is no proper return address. When it reaches the `ret` it will try to return to whatever value is on the top of the stack. This will likely cause your code to hang, reboot the system, or do other unexpected things.

A quick fix is to place a *JMP* instruction to skip over the code in `.empty_8042`. Something like this would do:

```
        out 0x60, al
        call .empty_8042 ;wait
        jmp .skip_function
    .empty_8042: ;For the 8042 function over this
        in al, 0x64
        test al, 2
        jnz .empty_8042
        ret
.skip_function:
    call check_a20  ;Check a20
```

It would be preferable to separate the `.empty_8042` function from the `seta20` function so that you don't need to unnecessarily jump over the `.empty_8042`. Your code could look like:

```
empty_8042:
    in al, 0x64
    test al, 2
    jnz empty_8042
    ret

seta20: ;Enable the a20 line if it worked then ax = 1 else 0
    pusha
    call check_a20 ;Check a20
    cmp ax, 1
    je .end ;If it worked then end function else:
    .keyboard: ;Test the 8042 keyboard controller
        call empty_8042
        mov al, 0xd1 ;command write
        out 0x64, al
        call empty_8042
        mov al, 0xdf ; A20 on
        out 0x60, al
        call empty_8042 ;wait

    call check_a20  ;Check a20
    cmp ax, 1
    je .end ;If it worked then end function else:
    .fasta20:
    in al, 0x92
    or al, 2
    out 0x92, al
    .end:
    popa
    call check_a20
    ret
```

Comment: Thanks it works and now 1 is outputted on the screen